# How to work with Magento REST API using Integration tokens?

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, postman

I have tried these steps

> Use the following steps to generate an access token:
>
> Log in to Admin and click System > Extensions > Integrations to
> display the Integrations page.
>
> Click Add New Integration to display the New Integration page.
>
> Enter a unique name for the integration in the Name field. Then enter
> your admin password in the Your Password field. Leave all other fields
> blank.
>
> Click the API tab. Select the Magento resources the integration can
> access. You can select all resources, or select a custom list.
>
> Click Save to save your changes and return to the Integrations page.
>
> Click the Activate link in the grid that corresponds to the
> newly-created integration.
>
> Click Allow.
>
> You can store this access token value in the system configuration and
> fetch it in code.

from another question [Is it good to use Access Token in Magento 2 for REST API?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/333398/is-it-good-to-use-access-token-in-magento-2-for-rest-api)

but seems it doesn't work when I try it in Postman. Eve if I give it all access.

```
{
    "message": "The consumer isn't authorized to access %resources.",
    "parameters": {
        "resources": "Magento_Catalog::products"
    }
}
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In previous versions of Commerce, the access token could be used on its own for token-based authentication. This behavior has been disabled by default due to the security implications of a never-expiring access token. Namely, if the access token is compromised it provides undetected persistent access to a store

However, while it is not recommended, this behavior can be restored in the Admin by setting the Stores > Configuration > Services > OAuth > Consumer Settings > Allow OAuth Access Tokens to be used as standalone Bearer tokens option to Yes. You can also enable this setting from the CLI by running the following command:

`bin/magento config:set oauth/consumer/enable_integration_as_bearer 1`

then flush cache

Please see the official docs here: [Token-based authentication](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token/)